# Rewrite both links and images in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How to make both links and images work in .htaccess
this is what i want

```
www.example.com/randomword --> /index/q1.php?encid=$1
www.example.com/anyname.jpg --> /index/img/q2.php?encid=$1
```

I tried this rewrite rule, but its not working

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index/q1.php?encid=$1 [N,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ ./index/img/q2.php?encid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

When i used the links individually it works fine, but when i combine, its not working

Comment: i tried using sub directory for images, which also not working
`RewriteRule ^index/(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ ./index/img/q2.php?encid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two .htaccess files for each rewrite rule. One in main folder and another in sub directory and its working.

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index/q1.php?encid=$1 [N,NC,QSA]
```

image/.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ ./q2.php?encid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: OR, you could have just reversed the order of your original directives. But remove the `N` flag from the first rule. The first (more generic) rule was catching _everything_. Also, remove the `./` prefix from the _substitution_.